# how to divide one column by another in in the same file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a very long file.txt that exceeds 1000000 rows, contains two columns as follows:

```
photon  electron
1000     100
1010     122
2000     50
1520     190
....     ....
```

I want a 3rd column as division: electron / photon
how can it possible in Python?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it come up short?  And which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I recommend using PANDAS to build a data frame.  From there, you should be able to easily add the column you want.  Examples are common on this site and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

One option using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\s+', header=0)

df['e/p'] = df['electron'] / df['photon']

print(df)
```

result:

```
   photon  electron       e/p
0    1000       100  0.100000
1    1010       122  0.120792
2    2000        50  0.025000
3    1520       190  0.125000
```

Same result without `pandas`, using standard-library:

```
import csv

d = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True))
    d += [data[0]]
    d[0].append('e/p')
    for l in list(data)[1::]:
        l.append(round(float(l[1])/float(l[0]), 6))
        d.append(l)

for i in d:
    print '{:<9} {:<9} {:<9}'.format(*i)
```

result:

```
photon    electron  e/p      
1000      100       0.1      
1010      122       0.120792 
2000      50        0.025    
1520      190       0.125
```

Format as desired for python2 or python3.